# Ajax/PHP works locally but not on host server

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I have a webform that allows people to post a status as part of my website. It works fine when posting from my locally hosted site however now I have the code on my live site it doesn't work.

Here is my form, file path is root/profile.php -

```
<div class="modal fade" id="post_form" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria- 
labelledby="postModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Post Something!</h5>
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
            </button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <p>This will appear on the user's profile page and also their newsfeed for your 
friends to see!</p>
            <form class="profile_post" action="" method="POST">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <textarea class="form-control" name="post_body"></textarea>
                    <input type="hidden" name="user_from" value="<?php echo $userLoggedIn; ?>">
                    <input type="hidden" name="user_to" value="<?php echo $username; ?>">
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" name="post_button" 
id="submit_profile_post">Post</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

The JS listener to process the post, file path is root/social/assets/js/listen.js -

```
$(document).ready(function() {
//Button for profile post
$('#submit_profile_post').off('click').on('click', function() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        async: false,
        url: "social/includes/handlers/ajax_submit_profile_post.php",
        data: $('form.profile_post').serialize(),
        success: function(msg) {
            $('#post_form').modal('hide');
          location.reload();
        },
        error: function () {
            alert("Failed to post!");
        }
    });
});
});
```

The content of the file the JS/AJAX calls, file path is root/social/includes/handlers/ajax_submit_profile_post.php-

```
require '../../config/config.php'; //getting $con var
include("../classes/User.php"); //Call in the USER CLASS
include("../classes/Post.php"); //Call in the Post CLASS
include("../classes/Notification.php"); //Call in the Post CLASS
if (isset($_POST['post_body'])) {
$post = new Post($con, $_POST['user_from']);
$post->submitPost($_POST['post_body'], $_POST['user_to'], ""); 
}
```

config.php contains the db connection and Post.php is the sql insert and works from a different form on the site. Can anyone see any issues with the code itself as to why it wouldn't work in a different environment? Both localhost and server are PHP 7.4.

When trying to post I get the error message 'Failed to Post!' as per the AJAX function.

I have tried changing the file paths as I thought this may be the issue but have so far been unable to find what might be the correct one.

Comment: Why off and why async: false ??

Comment: The code wasn't written by me, so that's as it came to me.

Comment: We'll need some useful debugging information such as error messages, more specific information about the point of failure, and so on, as identified by your investigative efforts so far. "Doesn't work" isn't a useful problem statement - it tells us precisely nothing about what might be going on. And we cannot run the code. If it's ok in one environment but not another then simply staring at the code is unproductive in the vast majority of cases. Also make sure you've shown us a [mre] of the issue with all relevant code and and data (but nothing which isn't related).

Comment: The "failed to post" message is also not useful as it's invented by the programmer purely for UI purposes and contains no technical information. All we know from that is that the response received from the server wasn't the expected one. But we don't know what that response actually was and we have no clues about why it might be. Have you actually opened up your browser's Developer Tools and the php logs on the server to do some basic technical investigation? It seems the main issue here may be simply that you've never learned how to do any proper debugging, or even basic error checks

Comment: My host doesn't store server logs, I've asked them about this several times. I've also tried debugging using the browser tools and get status code 500

Comment: 500 is severside error, without logs you can only add a lot of echo statements to determine where the error is

Comment: If they don't/won't store php error logs then you need to get another host because that's really poor practice, and it's really basic and easy to enable. But you can still (temporarily, if it's a live environment) enable php errors to be shown in the script output, and then look in the Response tab of the ajax request in the browser's Network tool to see the raw output including the error. We can't do anything to help without that specific error info - a 500 response  code just means the server code crashed, and there could be 1000 reasons for that

Comment: @ADyson Can you advise how I enable errors to be shown in the code?

Comment: @LeeFoster Try this, after you finish including and requiring everything, but before you do the if check:  `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors',1);` . This will display the errors, and it'll be easier for you to debug. Also, be sure to check if you actually receive anyting via POST, by doing `var_dump($_POST)` in your `ajax_submit_profile_post.php`.

Comment: @FiddlingAway var_dump returns - array(0) { }. Still no error messages even with error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors',1);

Comment: Are you actually looking in the response of the ajax request via the network tool? If you enabled error reporting for the correct script and looked in the correct place then, because there's a 500 error, there must be an error message. Remember that ajax responses don't show in your main page automatically

Comment: @ADyson In the response tab on of Network under DevTools it simply says 'This request has no response data available.' error reporting is set in ajax_submit_profile_post.php is this the correct place for it?

Comment: @LeeFoster What happens if you temporarily delete all the code in your `ajax_submit_profie_post.php`, and in its place have just a simple `echo 'test';`? If that works (`test` becomes visible in the Response part of your latest request in the browser's Network tab), try including one line of code at a time, and placing your `echo 'test';` underneath it.

Comment: @FiddlingAway Response shows 'Failed to load response data. No resource with given identifier found'

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead.

Makes more sense. No need to reload the page, then what is the point of using Ajax

```js
$(function() {
  
  $('#profile_post').on('submit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault()
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "social/includes/handlers/ajax_submit_profile_post.php",
      data: $(this).serialize(),
      success: function(msg) {
        $('#post_form').modal('hide');
      },
      error: function() {
        alert("Failed to post!");
      }
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="modal fade" id="post_form" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria- labelledby="postModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Post Something!</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
            </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>This will appear on the user's profile page and also their newsfeed for your friends to see!</p>
        <form class="profile_post" id="profile_post" action="" method="POST">
          <div class="form-group">
            <textarea class="form-control" name="post_body"></textarea>
            <input type="hidden" name="user_from" value="<?php echo $userLoggedIn; ?>">
            <input type="hidden" name="user_to" value="<?php echo $username; ?>">
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            <button class="btn btn-primary" name="post_button">Post</button>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Agree with the point about post-ajax reloads but not sure how this tinkering is going to fix the specific error the OP has (which at this point we dont even know what it is)

Comment: At least it won’t be the client code